# What is the proper way to link enums with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am getting linker errors (LNK2019) for a new enum class I added to my cmake (3.14) project. Individually, the projects compile in VS but fail when linking the main exe.
Here's the enum def:

```
#ifndef VERTEXBUFFERMODE_H
#define VERTEXBUFFERMODE_H

enum class BufferMode
{
    SingleCopy,
    InstanceCopy
};

#endif
```

I can fix it by instantiating my enum like this:

```
#ifndef VERTEXBUFFERMODE_H
#define VERTEXBUFFERMODE_H

enum class BufferMode
{
    SingleCopy,
    InstanceCopy
} BuffMode;

#endif
```

However, I get linker warnings LNK4006, that its already defined. Though the link succeeds, I would rather not have it.
In my CMakeLists.txt I have linked the project where the enum is defined (Core.Graphics):

> target_link_libraries(ExperimentalEngine      Core.Graphics       Infrastructure
>           ${ALL_LIBS}
>           )

**Update with exact error message:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: enum BufferMode
>   __cdecl VertexBuffer::bufferMode(void)" (?bufferMode@VertexBuffer@@QEAA?AW4BufferMode@@XZ) referenced in
>   function "private: void __cdecl VertexArray::drawArrays(class
>   VertexBuffer *)"
>   (?drawArrays@VertexArray@@AEAAXPEAVVertexBuffer@@@Z)  ExperimentalEngine  C:\work\temp\experimentalengine\Core.Graphics.lib(VertexArray.obj)  1

I believe this has to do with me not properly setting something in cmake. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show the exact error messages, not just the numbers/ids.

Comment: I've updated it with the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LNK2019` error message has nothing to do with your enum class.

The error message says that you have no definition for the public method `BufferMode bufferMode(void)` of your `VertexBuffer`.  You only declared it but you never added it's implementation.
(`public: enum BufferMode __cdecl VertexBuffer::bufferMode(void)`).

And the error occurs because `drawArrays` tries to use `bufferMode`.
(`referenced in function "private: void __cdecl VertexArray::drawArrays(class VertexBuffer *)`)

And writing:

```
enum class BufferMode
{
    SingleCopy,
    InstanceCopy
} BuffMode;
```

didn't fix the `LNK2019` error, it introduced a new one. So revert the `} BuffMode;` back to `};`. And add the missing definition for `bufferMode(void)`.

The whole error message structured with comments:

```
Error LNK2019 
 unresolved external symbol 
   "public: enum BufferMode __cdecl VertexBuffer::bufferMode(void)" // human readable version of the name
          (?bufferMode@VertexBuffer@@QEAA?AW4BufferMode@@XZ) // mangled version of the name above
 referenced in function 
   "private: void __cdecl VertexArray::drawArrays(class VertexBuffer *)" // human readable version of the name
          (?drawArrays@VertexArray@@AEAAXPEAVVertexBuffer@@@Z)  // mangled version of the name above
 ExperimentalEngine  
    C:\work\temp\experimentalengine\Core.Graphics.lib
        (VertexArray.obj)  // the translation unit for which the error occured
    1
```

Comment: Right! I missed defining it. Thanks for the detailed answer.